# Extract the shape of every objects in a black and white image

Tags: c++, math, image-processing

Given an image with a black background and white pixels denoting shapes, I want to extract the outer vertices of each shape.

I saw that [convex hull](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2018/03/16/what-is-the-shape-of-a-pixel/) solves it when the image has a single shape.
I also saw that alpha shapes somehow does what I want but I didn't see an example regarding images and pixels.

In this case though, what is the algorithm that allows me to extract a list of shapes and their outer vertices from a purely binary image?

Comment: What output do you want? All the pixel coordinates which are on the boundary? I ask this, because vertices don't exist in a pixel image (or at least, they exist only as an approximation).

Comment: yeah, the pixel coordinates are enough, then I retrieve the vertices coordinates on where I am using the image.

Comment: Try to search examples with OpenCV tag

Comment: I wanted to avoid using OpenCV, I wanted to know the algorithm so that I could implement myself.

Comment: You can identify pixels on the boundary very simply: if a pixel doesn't have all the 4 neighbors set, then it is on boundary

Comment: that is very true, although, how can you filter the outer points from all the boundary? I thought of that method too, but think about a square. how do you identify the four vertices? well, you may say that it needs two pixels unset and you are right because it is a convex shape, but what about concave shapes like for instance the inner points between each star arm.

Comment: @geza btw, I thought of giving up and include OpenCV in my project and using the contour recognition to obtain the boundary, but then, I don't know how to filter just the necessary points/pixels instead of the whole boundary.

Comment: Identifying boundary pixels are easy (I'm not sure, what do you mean by outer points). If a pixel is set, and it doesn't have all four neighbors set, then this is a boundary pixel. Identiyfing vertices is much harder. In fact, in the general case, cannot be done perfectly. For example: if your boundary is something like a circle, then what are the vertices? Is it a real circle? Is it a 1000-gon? A 576-gon?

Comment: Assuming you know how to get the convex hull of a single shape, you find the convex hull of multiple shapes by creating an image containing only one of the multiple shapes, finding the convex hull of that shape, then repeating for all of the shapes.

Comment: @beaker the thing is that I want to automate that, I don't want to point whose are the shapes in the image...

Comment: So it sounds like you need some sort of blob detection/connected component labeling to identify the individual shapes programatically.